# unable to match password field in java with oracle database

Tags: java, database, passwords, string-matching

I am trying to build a simple login form using Swing in Java. I created a Sample form with two fields.

1. usernamefield of type TextField
2. passfield of type PasswordField

Now I have a database and in that a login table which has following structure.

```
username   |  password
----------------------
   abcd    |   xyz
```

Also I created a connection to database. and I am able to access table data by using ResultSet.
I made an object of database connection called **conn**.
I know that password is stored in the form of char array.
so when I try to match password by using following code it does not work.

```
if(usernamefield.getText() == conn.username && passfield.getPassword().toString == conn.password) {
system.out.println("Correct");
}else {
system.out.println("Incorrect");
}
```

**Above code always go to else block.**
I also noticed that `passfield.getPassword()` prints the correct password while `passfield.getPassword().toString` prints some random characters like `[C@76dab03c`

How to resolve it?

Comment: You should use .equals() to compare strings, not the == operator.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus

Comment: `getPassword()` [returns array of characters instead of String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881291/why-is-char-preferred-over-string-for-passwords). Also even if it would return Strings, [you shouldn't compare them with `==`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).

Comment: I am from c/c++ background and new to Java that's why used == instead of .equals. now I have changed it and it is working correctly. I will surly look into hashing functions for password security. - thanks for suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Use `equals` instead of `==` and it should work. Never use == on strings, it hardly ever produces the result you expect.

I think the more serious issue with your code is that you're storing passwords in plain text. That is a huge security risk. You should look into password hashing algorithms, for instance bcrypt.

Comment: Passwords should be securely hashed, not encrypted.

Comment: bcrypt is not a hashing algorithm, it is Blowfish encryption last time I looked.

Comment: It's a cryptographic hash function.

Answer (score 0):

You must compare string with .equals(), not ==, but you're doing this wrong anyway. The password should be hashed at the database, and you should be passing what the user entered *to* the database and having *it* do the matching, via a WHERE clause using the appropriate hash function. In other words, ask the database to fetch the user row with this username and password.